# Why does maximum likelihood estimator perform very good in classification?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, high-dimensional

I have a binary response Y and a `n*p` X matrix as predictors, which `n = 100` and `p = 100000`. I use logistic regression function to build the classification model. $ \log \frac{p(Y=1|X)}{Y=0|X} = \beta_0 + \beta_iX$. I want to check the predictive performance of MLE in the high-dimensional setting. I use the cross-validation method with the `AUC` value as prediction criterion to check the predictive performance of `MLE`. Through the Glmnet function on training data, I obtain the MLE for each predictor X, then predict the test data set based on the MLEs. However, I got a very high AUC value. In my interpretation, the MLE should perform badly in `high-dimensional` setting, because the MLEs are not unique, the MLEs may be overestimated. Could anyone explain to me whether it is reasonable that the MLE perform very good in a high-dimensional setting? Why can it be that?

Comment: You should detail better your question, _e.g._ what kind of resampling (if any) are you using to obtain that AUC? Are you really sure your AUC computation is right?

Comment: @Firebug I have added some more details to my question. Can you check again?

Comment: Glmnet does not do maximum likelihood estimation. It penalizes the likelihood with a measure of model complexity, ie, regularization.